# Print all hours:minutes from 00:00 to 23:59

Tags: r, design-patterns, time, count

I would like to print all the hours: minutes in a day from 00:00 to 23:59.

This part goes beyond the question, but if you want to help me, this is the whole idea:

Once that is done, I would like to calculate all the "curious" times that can be interpreted as serendipities. Patterns like: 00:00, 22:22, 01:10, 12:34, 11:44, and the like.

Later on, I would like to count all the "serendipities", and divide them to the total number of hours to know the probabilities of find a "serendipity" each time a person look at the time on his smartphone.

To be honest, I am pretty lost. There is already some months without coding. For the first part of the problem, I guess that a loop can make the task. 
For the second part, an `if` conditional can probably make it.

For the first part of the problem I have tried loops like this

```
for(i in x){
  for(k in y){
    cat(i,":",k, ",")
  }
}
```

For the second, something like 
Assuming the digits of the time are `ab:cd`

```
if(a==b & a==c & a==d){
print(ab:cd)
TRUE
}

if(a==b & c==d){
print(ab:cd)
TRUE
}
```

I would like to get the whole list of numbers first. Then, the list of "serendipities", and finally the count of both to make the percentage. 
I find interesting how people find patterns in numbers when they look at the time, and I would like to know how probable is to get one of these patterns out of the `24*60 = 1440`
I hope I have explained myself. (I used to be better with coding and maths, but after some months, I have forgotten almost everything).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to generate the list of all possible times.

```
h <- seq(from=0, to=23)
m <- seq(from=0, to=59)

h <- sprintf('%02d', h)
m <- sprintf('%02d', m)

df <- data.frame(expand.grid(h, m))
df$times <- paste0(df$Var1, ':', df$Var2)

df <- df[order(df$times), ]
df$times
```

Partial output

```
df$times[1:25]
 [1] "00:00" "00:01" "00:02" "00:03" "00:04" "00:05" "00:06" "00:07" "00:08"
[10] "00:09" "00:10" "00:11" "00:12" "00:13" "00:14" "00:15" "00:16" "00:17"
[19] "00:18" "00:19" "00:20" "00:21" "00:22" "00:23" "00:24"
```

Length of variable

```
dim(df)
[1] 1440    3
```

Comment: (+1) You can make your code even shorter by omitting `c()` around `seq` (they are not necessary); you can avoid having to re-order by expanding the "grid" in reverse, i.e. first `m` then `h`. Lastly, the `sprintf` and `paste` commands can be collapsed to a single `sprintf` call. To create a simple vector of HH:MM strings, a one-liner would be `with(setNames(expand.grid(m, h), c("m", "h")), sprintf("%02i:%02i", h, m))`.

Comment: A much more elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

We can create a sequence of 1 minute interval starting from `00:00:00` to `23:59:00` and then use `format` to get output in desired format.

```
format(seq(as.POSIXct("00:00:00", format = "%T"), 
           as.POSIXct("23:59:00", format = "%T"), by = "1 min"), "%H:%M")

#[1] "00:00" "00:01" "00:02" "00:03" "00:04" "00:05" "00:06" "00:07" "00:08" "00:09" 
#    "00:10" "00:11" "00:12" "00:13" "00:14" "00:15" "00:16" "00:17" "00:18" "00:19" ...
```

Comment: thank you very much, indeed, this code seems really simple to apply =)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way of doing it:

```
> result <- character(1440)

> for (i in 0:1439) result[i+1L] <- sprintf("%02d:%02d",
+                                           i %/% 60,
+                                           i %% 60
+ ) 

> head(result)
[1] "00:00" "00:01" "00:02" "00:03" "00:04" "00:05"

> tail(result)
[1] "23:54" "23:55" "23:56" "23:57" "23:58" "23:59"
```